# changing the points size on matplotlib pyplot scatterplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I am trying to change the size of the points on my scatter plot, but I tried setting the size of the points to one size but it's not working.

code so far:

```
s = 10
plt.scatter(lon,lat,ocean_basins==84, s=s)
#plt.scatter(lon,lat,ocean_basins==30)
plt.show()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2e9ae9ad1587> in <module>
      1 s = 10
----> 2 plt.scatter(lon,lat,ocean_basins==84, s=s)
      3 #plt.scatter(lon,lat,ocean_basins==30)
      4 plt.show()
      5 

TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 's'
```

What is the problem? Why can't I change the point size? I am plotting 3D data, but I really would like to use a form of plt.scatter to be able to customize and designate different colors for the different ocean basins. and thus change the size of the dots.

[image]

Comment: [See order of arguments](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), it's `x`, `y`, `s`, `c`.   Your `ocean_basins==84` is not a variable or argument assignment, it is a boolean evaluation.  So that is taking the `s` position, and then you also pass `s` as a keyword.

Comment: oh I see... I cannot change ocean_basins==84... how can I remedy this issue? thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you attempting with `ocean_basins==84`? What is `ocean_basins`?

Comment: Yes; removing `ocean_basins==84` should fix it, but if you are using that expression for something, you need to point it to a different keyword argument

Comment: ocean_basins if the variable that I am plotting with respect to longitude and latitude. it's just a location. i tried renaming ocean_basins as a different variable, but i still get the same error...

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how `plt.scatter` works. More code would be helpful. You still haven't explained what *exactly* `ocean_basins` is.

Comment: Well that sounds like you are trying to make a 3-dimensional plot (`lon` x `lat` x `ocean_basins`)?  In which case `plt.scatter` is not appropriate I believe, as it is for 2D plots.  Also, what is with the `84` then?

Comment: oh yes.. i am trying make a 3d plot... but i want to differentiate between different ocean basins and how they look with respect to eachother (attaching photo) to the question.

Comment: Can't tell what `lon` and `lat` are from your latest edit. Please consider making a [reprex], including sample data and code as text, not just a screenshot.

Comment: With either `matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter()` or `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.scatter()`, if you simply want to increase the point size for all points, you can just set `s` to some number.  In both the code in your image, and the code in your example, you could do this.  The problem in your example is that you are positionally saying `s=ocean_basins==84`.

Comment: Also, in both your code and your image, the 2D version of `scatter` is being used, so you will not get a 3D plot